# display:table próximo do rodapé

Tags: html, css

Olá! Estou tentando deixar uma **div** proximo do **rodape**. 
Estou usando display:flex e com isso não consigo usar porcentagem.
Alguém pode me esclarecer como resolver isso de alguma forma...

```css
<style>
*{
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}
html {
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}

body {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    min-height: 100%;
}
 #quadro{
 margin-left:5px;
 margin-top:5px;
  width:auto;
 height: 100px;
 margin-bottom:5px;
 border:1px solid black;
 }
footer {
    margin-top: auto;
    width:100%;
    height:5px;
    background:black;
}
</style>
```

```html
<body>
<html>
<div id="quadro">
</div>
<footer>
</footer>
</html>
</body>
```

Answer (score -3):

Não seria melhor tu usares o *"display: inline;"* ou talvez *"display: inline-block;"*, pq você pode obter mais ou menos o mesmo resultado podendo alterar o tamanho com porcentagem.